# StartSonar Wrapper Stopped Error

Tags: sonarqube

I am new to using Sonar. I am trying to run Sonar Server but getting error

```
    wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
    wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
    jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
    jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights 
    Reserved.
    jvm 1    |
    jvm 1    | 2017.12.01 11:20:53 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning 
    or creating temp directory C:\sonarqube-6.5\temp
   jvm 1    | 2017.12.01 11:20:54 INFO  app[]
    [o.s.a.p.JavaProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[es]: C:\Program 
    Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -
       Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -
    XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -
   XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -
   Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonarqube-6.5\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* 
     org.sonar.search.SearchServer C:\sonarqube-6.5\temp\sq-
   process3727603115591368728properties
    jvm 1    | 2017.12.01 11:21:01 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] 
Process[es] is up
 jvm 1    | 2017.12.01 11:21:01 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.JavaProcessLauncherImpl] 
 Launch process[web]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\java -
 Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -
  XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonarqube-6.5\temp -cp 
   ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;C:\sonarqube-6.5\lib\jdbc\h2\h2-1.3.176.jar 
   org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\sonarqube-6.5\temp\sq-
   process5462578831133863784properties
   jvm 1    | 2017.12.01 11:21:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process 
    [web] is stopped
   jvm 1    | 2017.12.01 11:21:03 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process 
     [es] is stopped
    jvm 1    | 2017.12.01 11:21:03 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] 
      SonarQube is stopped
     wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

checking the log for web getting error 
     Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-
      0.0.0.0-9000"]java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
I am not sure what is solution for this problem I have changed Java Path in wrapper.conf as well added path in environment variable also.
Kindly help me with this.

Comment: The java runtime seems not to be the problem here. Could you please add the content of the other log files (especially web.log) to your question? My guess is, that port 9000 is already in use or there is a problem with your configuration (maybe database connection).

Comment: Yes there is an error for port 9000 Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind.I am not sure how to fix it @slartidan

Answer (score 2):

> ProtocolHandler ["http-nio- 0.0.0.0-9000"]java.net.BindException: Address already in use

This kind of error means that another process is listening on port 9000.
Check a few things:

- Do you already have another instance of SonarQube running?

  - Go to `localhost:9000` in a browser
- Do you have another process that might be using this port?

  - Check the list of running processes. On Linux you can use `netstat -ntlp | grep :9000` to find what's running on port 9000

Once you have identified what else is using port 9000 there are several solution paths:

- Kill the other process
- Change the configuration of the other process or SonarQube to use a different port

Comment: Was able to solve the issue by changing port in sonar properties

Answer (score 0):

That is becauseof the port already in use so kill the port and use.
with WINDOWS10 default tools:

Step 1: Open Windows PowerShell as Administrator

Step 2: Find PID (ProcessID) for port 8080:

netstat -aon | findstr 9000

```
TCP 0.0.0.0:8080 0.0.0.0:0 LISTEN 77777
```

Step 3: Kill the zombie process:

taskkill /f /pid 77777

where "77777" is your PID

Answer (score 0):

I had a perfect solution for this you just need to kill the process of sonarqube. If you are using windows machine I have these steps for you:-

1. Press the Windows key on your keyboard, type resmon.exe and press Enter.
2. In the window that appears, click the CPU tab.
3. In the third bar from the top, see the label Associated Handles.
4. Type the name of the file you're trying to close into the Search Handles bar, and then
   click the magnifying glass icon.
5. Locate the program that is using your file.
6. Right-click the program using the file in question and select End Process.